# Matlab Huffman Encoding in matrix

Tags: matlab, huffman-code

I am trying to encode a matrix that i have (after calculating frame differences) with Huffman code but i am having difficulties completing it

The matrix i wish to encode with huffman is called "amp"

Something that i found is this:

```
function y = mat2huff(x)
%MAT2HUFF Huffman encodes a matrix.
%   Y = MAT2HUFF(X) Huffman encodes matrix X using symbol
%   probabilities in unit-width histogram bins between X's minimum
%   and maximum values. The encoded data is returned as a structure
%   Y: 
%      Y.code   The Huffman-encoded values of X, stored in
%               a uint16 vector.  The other fields of Y contain
%               additional decoding information, including:
%      Y.min    The minimum value of X plus 32768
%      Y.size   The size of X
%      Y.hist   The histogram of X
%
%   If X is logical, uint8, uint16, uint32, int8, int16, or double,
%   with integer values, it can be input directly to MAT2HUFF. The
%   minimum value of X must be representable as an int16.  
%
%   If X is double with non-integer values---for example, an image
%   with values between 0 and 1---first scale X to an appropriate
%   integer range before the call. For example, use Y =
%   MAT2HUFF(255*X) for 256 gray level encoding.   
%
%   NOTE: The number of Huffman code words is round(max(X(:))) -
%   round(min(X(:))) + 1.  You may need to scale input X to generate
%   codes of reasonable length.  The maximum row or column dimension
%   of X is 65535. 
%
%   See also HUFF2MAT.

%   Copyright 2002-2004 R. C. Gonzalez, R. E. Woods, & S. L. Eddins
%   Digital Image Processing Using MATLAB, Prentice-Hall, 2004
%   $Revision: 1.5 $  $Date: 2003/11/21 15:21:12 $

if ndims(x) ~= 2 | ~isreal(x) | (~isnumeric(x) & ~islogical(x))
   error('X must be a 2-D real numeric or logical matrix.');
end

% Store the size of input x.
y.size = uint32(size(x));

% Find the range of x values and store its minimum value biased
% by +32768 as a UINT16.
x = round(double(x));
xmin = min(x(:));
xmax = max(x(:));
pmin = double(int16(xmin));
pmin = uint16(pmin + 32768);    y.min = pmin;

% Compute the input histogram between xmin and xmax with unit
% width bins, scale to UINT16, and store.
x = x(:)';
h = histc(x, xmin:xmax);
if max(h) > 65535
    h = 65535 * h / max(h);
end
h = uint16(h);   y.hist = h;

% Code the input matrix and store the result.
map = huffman(double(h));          % Make Huffman code map
hx = map(x(:) - xmin + 1);         % Map image
hx = char(hx)';                    % Convert to char array
hx = hx(:)';
hx(hx == ' ') = [];                % Remove blanks
ysize = ceil(length(hx) / 16);     % Compute encoded size
hx16 = repmat('0', 1, ysize * 16); % Pre-allocate modulo-16 vector
hx16(1:length(hx)) = hx;           % Make hx modulo-16 in length
hx16 = reshape(hx16, 16, ysize);   % Reshape to 16-character words
hx16 = hx16' - '0';                % Convert binary string to decimal
twos = pow2(15:-1:0);
y.code = uint16(sum(hx16 .* twos(ones(ysize, 1), :), 2))';

 ...
```

But in the above code how do i declare to use my matrix called "amp"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call your function `huf_amp = mat2huf(amp);` huf_amp being the structure detailed in your code sample.

Comment: Great! I managed to do this..However matlab returns the following error "P must be a real numeric vector." and it has to do with another file called huffman.m Do you know what can i do?

Comment: You should learn how to debug with Matlab, use a breakpoint and then step by step check if the variables in your workspace are of the right type. In your particular case, variable h is probably not initialized properly and thus is not a real numeric vector; so your parameter x is surely wrong.